# BeautifulSoup как выделить только тэг, для проверки условия

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

помогите с таким вопросом.
Нужно пройти последовательно по всем тэгам страницы и если тэг равен `<h2></h2>`, нужно выполнить действия со значением тэга.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
    for line in soup:
      if line - как здесь понять что line имеет или нет тэг <h2></h2>?
```

по поиску выдает только получение значения по тэгу, а как получить сам тэг из элемента?

Answer (score 0):

В общем копался в документации, нашел такой вариант:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
a = soup.strings
for i in a:
    if i.parent.name == 'h2'
        print(i)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).